# Apply a compound path over a clipping mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a vectorial image which is fairly complex (got it off the web) and it is some kind of a circle. While the center of this circle is white it is not transparent. I've been trying to apply a compound path over the image which has a clipping mask and I get this error from Illustrator:

```
Cannot make a compound path. A compound path cannot combine a clipping mask with an ordinary path.
```

Would you know how to do this or how to actually make the center of the circle transparent while being in a clipping mask.

Here's the link to the actual image:  http://www.free-vector-design.com/background-vector/abstract-circle-vector-1.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turn the whole group of swirly shapes into symbol. Then it will let you apply a clipping mask to it.

To create a symbol

1. Select the whole set of shapes (you don't nee to group them)
2. Open the Symbol menu (Window->Symbols or Shift+Ctrl+F1)
3. Create a new symbol (either drag the group of shapes into the window or select New Symbol from the top right menu of the Symbol window)

AI will let you apply clipping masks to symbols without worrying about how they are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Make the compound shape first. Then select it and the art and create a clipping mask.

That's the best I can offer since "center of the circle" is not anywhere remotely descriptive of the exact area you are trying to alter or mask. That image is made up of literally hundreds of circles.